# I'm looking for an iPhone/Mobile app to to aggregate alerts

Tags: notifications, push

I am looking to find an app like pushover, which I can aggregate multiple alerts into.  I want to be able to via API add and remove alerts.  Badges should be shown for alerts pending, I would like to be able to add and remove alerts via api which would update badge accordingly.  If i open app I would like to have the ability to click on alert and it open url set via api.  Wondering if this exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this exists. Spontit, I believe, does what you're looking for.

Here is the [web-app](https://spontit.com/) and [the API docs](https://api.spontit.com/).